# delay between requests using github3 in python

Tags: python, python-requests, github3.py

I'm using python github3 module and i need to set delay between request to github api, because my app make to much load on server.

I'm doing things such as

```
git = github3.GitHub()
for i in itertools.chain(git.all_repositories(), git.repositories(type='private')):
    do things
```

I found that GitHub use requests to make request to github api.
https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/3e251f2a066df3c8da7ce0b56d24befcf5eb2d4b/github3/models.py#L233

But i can't figure out what parameter i should pass or what atribute i should change to set some delay between the requests.

Can you advise me something?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "my app make too much load on server"? Are you hitting a request limit imposed by the GitHub API? If so, why not catch the corresponding HTTP response and implement a back off?

Answer (score 0):

github3.py presently has no options to enforce delays between requests. That said, there is a way to get the request metadata which includes the number of requests you have left in your ratelimit as well as when that ratelimit should reset. I suggest you use `git.rate_limit()['resources']['core']` to determine what delays you should set for yourself inside your own loop.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function when I expect to exceed my query limit:

```
def wait_for_karma(gh, min_karma=25, msg=None):
    while gh:
        core = gh.rate_limit()['resources']['core']
        if core['remaining'] < min_karma:
            now = time.time()
            nap = max(core['reset'] - now, 0.1)
            logger.info("napping for %s seconds", nap)
            if msg:
                logger.info(msg)
            time.sleep(nap)
        else:
            break
```

I'll call it before making a call that I believe is "big" (i.e. could require multiple API calls to satisfy). Based on your code sample, you may want to do this at the bottom of your loop:

```
git = github3.GitHub()
for i in itertools.chain(git.all_repositories(), git.repositories(type='private')):
    do_things()
    wait_for_karma(git, msg="pausing")
```